# Weird dependencies for gnome-tetris

Tags: package-management

I tried to install [`games-tetris`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/games-tetris) because that's the only one returned by `aptitude search tetris`:

```
# aptitude install games-tetris
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  angrydd bastet blockout2 crack-attack cuyo cuyo-data{a} flobopuyo 
  fonts-sil-gentium{a} fonts-sil-gentium-basic{a} freealchemist 
  freeglut3{a} frozen-bubble frozen-bubble-data{a} games-tasks games-tetris 
  gemdropx ghextris gtetrinet libadns1{a} libalien-sdl-perl{a} 
  liballegro4.4{a} libboost-program-options1.58.0{a} 
  libcapture-tiny-perl{a} libclass-inspector-perl{a} 
  libcompress-bzip2-perl{a} libfile-sharedir-perl{a} libgconf2-4{a} 
  libidl0{a} liborbit2{a} libportmidi0{a} libsdl-gfx1.2-5{a} 
  libsdl-pango1{a} libsdl-perl{a} libsdl-ttf2.0-0{a} libsmpeg0{a} 
  libtie-simple-perl{a} ltris netris petris python-gconf{a} 
  python-glade2{a} python-gnome2{a} python-numpy{a} python-pygame{a} 
  python-pyorbit{a} stax tasksel tasksel-data{a} tetrinet-client tetrinetx 
  tint xbubble xbubble-data{a} xwelltris 
0 packages upgraded, 54 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 51.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 90.8 MB will be used.
```

***wtf***?!

54 packages? 51.5MB d/l? 91MB on disk? For *tetris*?!

Let us look closely here, what dependencies do we see?

- perl & python - scripting languages
- stax, netris, petris - tetris variants? I need just one!
- gconf, bzip2, sdl, mpeg - why does tetris need these?!

I would have reported this as a bug, but this does not look like a *bug* (i.e., a mistake which can be fixed by the author), this looks like insanity incarnate.

You would take your car to the mechanic if it makes weird noises, but what if the car starts talking to you in sonnets and refuses to make left turns on Tuesdays?

So, can someone please explain to me why installing a tetris game requires  both perl and python bindings to dozens libraries?

Comment: Just strange that I get over 20 results for `apt-cache search tetris`... Which repositories do you have enabled and which Ubuntu version do you use??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a bug. The package `games-tetris` is a **meta package** and installs

**Debian's tetris-like games**

as you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/games-tetris) and `games-tetris` **isn't** gnome-tetris.

Install the game of your choice, [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/games-tetris) is the list. Or install a Tetris-like game for Gnome

```
sudo apt-get install quadrapassel
```

but think of it. Also this game have dependencies **;)**

---

To search Tetris-like games use

```
aptitude search '~dtetris'
```

or

```
apt-cache search tetris
```

---

> So, can someone please explain to me why installing a tetris game
>   requires both perl and python bindings to dozens libraries?

Yes, ask the developers of the games, why they have decided to use Perl, Python and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is installing other games. Perhaps it is part of a game-pack since [crack attack](http://www.nongnu.org/crack-attack/) is a separate game? That is crazy though installing all of that just to play tetris. Some tetris games below:

```
sudo apt-get install blockout2
sudo apt-get install xwelltris
sudo apt-get install gtetrinet
sudo apt-get install kblocks
```